# Is that structure even grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Ive read the following relative clause:

> ... that control which recipient a message is sent to

If I look at

> which recipient a message is sent to

"recipient" is the subject and "a message" is the object. Then we have the word order subject object verb. So its false? If its not false, why isn't it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it unless you're going to object to ending a sentence with a preposition (which few people do nowadays), in which case it would have to be _to which recipient a message is sent_.

Comment: A minor correction: You mean *incorrect*, not *false*.  *False* means something like "not matching a true fact".   For example, "Two pluses a two is equals the four" is *grammatically incorrect*, but not *false*; "Two plus two equals five" is grammatically correct, but false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A message" is the subject, "recipient" is the indirect object. The clause is passive. Compare:

"Every morning, I send a message to all members of staff" (active - the subject is "I")

"Every morning, a message is sent to all members of staff" (passive - the subject is "a message").

You can also clearly see that "a message" is the subject, because the verb agrees with it. We can demonstrate this by changing "a message" to "the messages", watch:

"... which recipient the messages **are sent** to"

But if we turn "recipient" into "recipients" nothing happens:

"... which recipients a message **is sent** to"

Comment: Ok even if the sentence is in passive. Why can you place the indirect object before the subject? Is that object fronting? Don't you need to write it as "which recipient, the messages are sent to?"

Comment: @HansMustermann Well no, "which songs I listen to", "which people I talk to", "which of the various advisers, civil servants and assorted hangers-on the prime minister meets with", etc. etc. It's standard grammar and it follows the same pattern as other relative clauses. "It controls which recipient the messages are sent to" is no different to "it controls what food I eat" which is no different to "it controls what I eat"

Comment: Thank you I got its another relative clause in a relativ clause.